# R - Markdown "! Missing { inserted. <to be read again> " mistake

Tags: r, latex, markdown, formula, hat

When I try to export in pdf a R Markdown file I get the following mistake:

```
! Missing { inserted. <to be read again>
```

The concerned line is this one:

```
$$
AIC = ln \hat{\sigma}^{2}_\hat{u_t} + \frac{2n_k}{T}
$$
```

I do not get what is wrong with the way I structure the formula.
FYI when I export in .doc it works fine, so all the problems start when I try no knit on pdf!

Anyone has suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's having trouble with your complicated subscript, `\hat{u_t}` -- try enclosing that entire term in `{ }`.

Comment: Unrelatedly: note also that if you replace `ln` with `\ln`, you'll get a nicer typesetting on those letters.

Comment: Great suggestion! Thank you!